# ¿Como leer un binario en C?

Tags: c, archivo, punteros, fread

Estoy intentando leer lo que hay en un binario pero al imprimirlo por pantalla
imprime solo una parte de lo que esta en el archivo.

El contenido del archivo bin es:

```
{   nombre1.txt                              /hY /hY|   nombre2.txt                             £«å\ãä·\–   claves.txt                            Þð]{¶û\—   perfil.exe                  ª›          È—¹\Y—¹\ª   system.doc                  4L  
      »Æ¹]ûÿ‹]ô  master.bin                  Ø         ‡W<]‹.-]È   reset.exe                   U@ï  
      {r0] NrSù  clock.out                   4           ªoa]      Max.txt t                   Ð   
       ç¸_g¶_Z  config.xls                  Íˆ°        Aú“]ûX’]o   secreto.txt                 Ý    
         Ä“l_³k_“   video.avi t                 Örå8       ñh_vøb_M  init.bin  t                              €ì†]€ì†]  history.mp3                 û$/ 
       Kú“]Kú“]  format.exe                  &ê           ¸«5]ˆ5]  delete.exe                                ^_ ^_  boot.cfg e                  ÿn        Ðj_@ò__  zombi.inx                   QÐ 
      @!m_³k_  sony.bin                    î   
        »e_:O`_¤   pepe.mpg                    þT       ‘k_³k_
```

Pero solo imprime por pantalla lo siguiente del archivo:

```
@!m_³k_
```

Este es el código fuente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main(){

    FILE *binario;
    char buffer[500];


    binario=fopen("archivos.bin","rb");

    if(!binario){
        printf("no se puede acceder al archivo\n");
    }
    else{
        while(fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,binario));
        printf("%s",buffer);
    }

    fclose(binario);
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar me ayudaría muchísimo desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema está en estas lineas:

```
while(fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,binario));
printf("%s",buffer);
```

En vez de leer en el buffer e imprimir lo leido a medida que se lee del archivo,
lo que hace es leer el archivo hasta el final con `fread` y luego imprimir como
cadena la última parte.

Esto sucede porque la sentencia while puede tener un cuerpo vacio, y el "punto
y coma" marca el fin de la sentencia, asi que el printf no forma parte del cuerpo.
Para arreglarlo, hay que mover el printf al cuerpo del while, preferiblemente
entre llaves (`{}`):

```
while(fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,binario)) {
    printf("%s",buffer);
}
```

Otro problema es que el especificador de formato "%s" de printf solo sirve para
cadenas terminadas con el caracter nulo, y `buffer` no es una. Para escribir
un arreglo de bytes (que pueda contener caracteres nulos) a la salida estándar
se puede usar `fwrite` de la siguiente forma:

```
size_t leido;
while ((leido = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), binario))) {
    fwrite(buffer, leido, 1, stdout);
}
```

Nota que cambie de posición en la lista de argumentos el tamaño del buffer
con el "número de miembros" (nmemb) porque `fread` devuelve la cantidad de bytes
leida solo si el tamaño de cada miembro es 1.

El código final:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main(){

    FILE *binario;
    char buffer[500];


    binario=fopen("archivos.bin","rb");

    if(!binario){
        printf("no se puede acceder al archivo\n");
    }
    else{
        size_t leido;
        while ((leido = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), binario))) {
            fwrite(buffer, leido, 1, stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(binario);
}
```